# not recieving the textbox value in the function

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

'''
basically i am trying to make a textbox to take input from the user and opening with some default name and changing it to user given name in another textbox but the value of the textbox always is eter a none or empty string which raises an error
'''

```
   `nweb=Toplevel()
    nweb.configure(background='blue')
    nweb.geometry('1366x768')
   
    fram.destroy()
   
   n1=Label(nweb,text='enter the following details:',font='Aerial 16',fg='yellow',bg='blue').grid(column=0,row=1) 
   n2=Label(nweb,text='DONGLE',font='Aerial 100',fg='yellow',bg='blue').grid(column=0,row=0)
   n3=Label(nweb,text='website name:',font='Aerial 10',fg='yellow',bg='blue').grid(column=0,row=2) 
   edit = Text(nweb, width=50, height=1)
   edit.grid(column=1,row=2)
   n5=Label(nweb,text='keywords (write it in words as sentence):',font='Aerial 10',fg='yellow',bg='blue').grid(column=0,row=4) 
   edit2 = Text(nweb, width=50, height=1)
   edit2.grid(column=1,row=4)

   st=edit2
     
   def getdetail():
     def webcontent():
        webcon=Toplevel()
        webcon.geometry('1366x768')
        webcon.configure(background='blue')
             
        text = Text(webcon)  
        text.insert('1.0','ENTER YOUR WEBSITE CONTENT:')  
        text.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH,expand=1)

        if text.get(1.0,END)!='':
           with open('C:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\MUSTAFA\'S PROJECT FILES\\websites\\1234.dat','ab') as f1:
              pickle.dump(text.get(1.0,END),f1)
           os.rename('1234.dat',str(st))      
              
     err=False
     try:
        with open('search.dat','rb') as f1:
             while True:
                l=pickle.load(f1)
                if l[0]==edit.get(1.0,END):
                   g=Label(nweb,text='webite already taken',fg='red',bg='blue').grid(column=0,row=6) 
                   err=True
                elif 'www.' not in edit.get(1.0,END) and '.com' not in edit.get(1.0,END) :
                   g=Label(nweb,text='inappropriate webite name',fg='red',bg='blue').grid(column=0,row=6) 
                   err=True

     except EOFError:
          if not(err):  
                 with open('search.dat','ab') as f1:
                    l=[edit.get(1.0,END),edit2.get(1.0,END)]
                    pickle.dump(l,f1)
       
                 edit.delete(1.0,END)
                 edit2.delete(1.0,END)
                 webcontent()
                 
   create=Button(nweb, text='enter' , command=getdetail, bg='yellow').grid(column=0,row=5)`
```

'''and i have tried everything from tkinter variables to python variables if u help me out it will be very kind of u'''

Comment: Please fix the indentation of code and use triple backtick for formatting as code and i think it should be `text.get(1.0,'end-1c')` instead of `text.get(1.0,END)` which is used for `Entry` widgets?

Comment: i tried but that also doesnt seem help much

Comment: Where do you assume the failure?

Comment: @mohammedDhuleb this is a really small error. Try to debug by yourself. just follow your variable by typing `print(my_variable)` and see where it get lost. If you need further help, we are here.